# Multi-layered CAD files mark-up in autodesk-viewer

Tags: javascript, autodesk, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

When I try to draw a mark-up for multi-layered CAD files in [autodesk-viewer](/questions/tagged/autodesk-viewer), the font size or the thickness of markup tools is much larger than other CAD Files. The mark-up works fine for other CAD files except for multi-layered 3D files. What is the reason behind this? How do I solve this issue?

[image: Mark up for single layer 3D files. This is working fine.]

Comment: can you add more information on your markup script? On 3D the markup is bounded to that view, but you mentioned layered, is it a 2D?

Comment: any other information? otherwise I cannot help you... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Double check the layers 'units' in the DWG file, with Autocad.

You will notice that layers can have different 'units'.
Try modifying the units in each layer so they are the same 'units' of measure.  Save it, upload it, and test in the Viewer.
I've seen this issue with 2D layers, but not 3D, but I suspect it's the same issue.